# jquery datepicker month/year jumbled

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsp, datepicker

I'm using the jquery datepicker, but when the calendar pop-up shows, the month and year text are a jumbled mess to the extreme right of the calendar title bar.

I played with the css a bit but, to be bluntly honest, I don't have too much time to play with it.

Any help would be sorely appreciated.

I'd post a picture of the problem, but sof won't allow me to until I get 10 reputation(?) points.

The HTML:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>ADC Visitor Log</title>
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" /-->
        <style type="text/css">
            textarea{
                font: bold;
            }
        @media print {
            @page         { zoom: 93% }
        }
        div.footer { position: relative; }
        div > span { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
        .ui-datepicker {  
            width: 216px;  
            height: auto;  
            margin: 5px auto 0;  
            text-align: left;
            font: 9pt Arial, sans-serif;  
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);  
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);  
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);  
        }
        .ui-datepicker-title {  
text-align: center;  
}
   </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script-->
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        });

        function formSubmit(val){
            var dp = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
            var fp = document.getElementById("floor").value;
            var op = document.getElementById("officer").value;
            if(!dp.length==0){
                if(!fp.length==0){
                    if(!op.length==0){
                        //alert("still made it thru");
                        document.getElementById("frm1").action = "VL2";
                        document.getElementById("frm1").method = "POST";
                        document.getElementById("frm1").submit();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">VISITOR LOG</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div align="center">
        <h3>Please set visitor log data:</h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form id="frm1" action="VL2" method="POST">
            <div style="background-color: gray">
                <table>
                    <tr style="width: 100%">
                        <td width="33%" align="center">
                            <label>Floor: &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <select style="vertical-align: center;" name="floor" id="floor">
                                    <option>Select Floor</option>
                                    <option value="2nd">2nd</option>
                                    <option value="4th">4th</option>
                                    <option value="6th">6th</option>
                                </select>
                                </div>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="hidden" name="type" value="initial" size="0" /></td>
                        <td width="33%" align="center">
                            Date: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" 
                                                     name="datepicker" id="datepicker" 
                                                     style="background-color: #f5ffff; border: none;"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="33%" align="center">
                            <label>Officer: &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input name="officer" id="officer" size="40"
                                       style="background-color: #f5ffff; border: none;"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 30%; vertical-align: middle">
                <input align="center" type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You can still post a jsfiddle

Comment: And tidy your HTML up a little to make your problem more clear so we can help

Comment: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YkdZ4/). The year is beneath the title arrow on right.

Comment: @97ldave:  Yeah, this was a rush item that went from concept to deployment in about a day-and-a-half.  Didn't have time for niceties, and I appreciate y'alls forbearance on the ugly code.

Comment: It was more just so we could give you more help. Seems you have an answer anyway ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's this line of CSS that's causing your issue:

```
    div > span { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```

Remove this and the calendar displays correctly again.

Your selector is currently too generic (so it's picking up every span that's a direct child of a div) and should be rewritten to be more specific to your intended use.

See the Fiddle with that line of CSS removed here: http://jsfiddle.net/YkdZ4/1/

It looks like you're using that line to align everything in the grey bar to the bottom, is that correct?  Since you're using a table anyway, you can use valign="bottom" on the parent cells to get the effect you're after, without the all-encompassing CSS line from above.

See the updated HTML markup (and removed CSS line) in this Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YkdZ4/2/

Comment: That did it.  The span was in place for something else (a form number), but I forgot to delete it when I moved it to another page.

Answer (score 0):

remove position:absolute from below code

```
div > span { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; }
```